# Outputting files into subdirectories

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I want to run an `egrep` for several different patterns on a folder full of texts and output the results into corresponding folders. I'm also trying to make this neat and concise as this is a workflow I'll probably be using a lot.

So I have a folder full of texts called `docs` and I want to find two different regex patterns (regex1 and regex2) and output them into `docs/regex1` and `docs/regex2`

I would guess that something like this would work

```
mkdir {docs/regex1,docs/regex2}
for file in docs/*
do
    egrep -o -f regex1 "$file" > regex1/"${file%.*}"_regex1.txt
    egrep -o -f regex2 "$file" > regex2/"${file%.*}"_regex2.txt
done
```

This gives me the error:

```
regex1/docs/001_regex1.txt: No such file or directory
regex2/docs/001_regex2.txt: No such file or directory
```

For each file. How can I set the output do go into docs/regex1 instead of trying to go to regex1/docs?

Answer (score 1):

In your example script, you have:

```
egrep -o -f regex1 "$file" > regex1/"${file%.*}"_regex1.txt
egrep -o -f regex2 "$file" > regex2/"${file%.*}"_regex2.txt
```

But then you ask:

> For each file. How can I set the output do go into docs/regex1 instead of trying to go to regex1/docs?

You're explicitly placing `regex1` at the beginning of the path to which you're redirecting output.  Simply fix this to match what you want, and strip the leading path off of `$file`:

```
egrep -o -f regex1 "$file" > docs/regex1/"$( basename "${file%.*}" )"_regex1.txt
egrep -o -f regex2 "$file" > docs/regex2/"$( basename "${file%.*}" )"_regex2.txt
```